# Как вывести вместо одной записи из таблицы базы данных несколько других записей из другой таблицы по условию?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы и пример их заполнения:

Таблица Основная:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Второстепенная:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести на экран данные из этих двух таблиц таким образом, чтобы в Основной таблице в тех записях, где значение столбца split равно 1 вместо этих записей выводились записи из Второстепенной таблицы (по id этой записи).

Пример вывода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли реализовать такой комплексный запрос в базу данных? Чтобы на выходе получился готовый ассоциативный массив, который можно было бы вывести на экран и легко с ним работать (фильтровать, сортировать и тд)?

Comment: Какая версия mysql у вас используется?

Comment: Структура БД явно избыточна. Как вы намерены поддерживать целостность и непротиворечивость данных на такой структуре-то, хотелось бы знать...

Comment: @Akina А в чем избыточность и проблематичность? В том, что одна и та же сумма и количество товара собираться 2 раза в разных таблицах? Если, да, то это так и задумывалось для сверки итоговых сумм. А если нет, то как по другому можно реализовать? Ещё раз в кратце опишу, что нужно сделать. Есть необходимость разделять товар на разные адреса (location). Допустим, 2 штуки находятся в Москве, 1 штука в Питере и 3 штуки в Ярославле (на примере Отвёртки из моего примера).

Comment: *А в чем избыточность и проблематичность?* 1) Что мешает sum оказаться НЕ равным price*quantity? в обоих таблицах.. 2) Что мешает точно так же разойтись main.quantity и SUM(slave.quantity)? main.sum и SUM(slave.sum)?

Comment: @SwaD версия mysql 8.0.30

Comment: @Akina в main таблице абсолютно всегда sum будет равно quantity * price . За это можно даже не переживать.

Comment: *в main таблице абсолютно всегда sum будет равно quantity * price* Чем и как это обеспечивается? ответ типа "клиентским ПО" - откровенная глупость, и соответственно не принимается. Но если по первому пункту проблема фиксится вычисляемым полем, то вот по второму - разве что набором триггеров, и то без гарантий. *это так и задумывалось для сверки итоговых сумм. А если нет, то как по другому можно реализовать?* Есть такой термин - двойная бухгалтерия. Полюбопытствуйте на досуге...

Comment: @Akina "Чем и как это обеспечивается?" В подробности вдаваться не буду, надо просто как факт это принять и не строить никаких глупых теорий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с джойнами:

```
SELECT m.id
    , m.name
    , m.price
    , IFNULL(s.qunatity, m.quantity) AS qnt 
    , IFNULL(s.sum, m.sum) AS sum
FROM main_table AS m
LEFT JOIN slave_table AS s ON (
    s.id_item = m.id
    AND m.split = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, ты имеешь в виду так называемые [Join'ы](https://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/kak-rabotaet-sql-join)

Например, в твоём случае (если я неправильно понял, поправь):

```
SELECT * FROM `Основная` JOIN `Второстепенная` ON `Основная`.id=`Второстепенная`.id_item WHERE `Основная`.split = 1
```

Чтобы менять названия полей, можно использовать [Alias](https://oracleplsql.ru/aliases-mysql.html). Нужно лишь указать везде, где нужно кастомное название столбца таблицы, ключевое слово `AS`

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой, и в то же время, наверное, самый производительный путь - два отдельных подзапроса и объединение результатов:

```
  SELECT name, price, quantity, sum
  FROM maintable
  WHERE split IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT maintable.name, slavetable.price, slavetable.quantity, slavetable.sum
  FROM maintable
  JOIN slavetable ON maintable.id = slavetable.item_id
  WHERE maintable.split IS NOT NULL;
```